# Allow 0 quantity values in wishlist

Tags: ce-1.9.0.1, wishlist

I would like to change default wishlist behaviour in Magento CE 1.9. By default item is removed from wishlist if quantity value set to 0. I would like to keep it in the wishlist. I would also like that when items are added to wishlist, default quantity is 0 not 1. Is this possible, any ideas?

Comment: One of the ideas was to create observer for  "checkout_cart_update_items_before" event and set $buyRequest->setQty($itemInfo['qty']);  to 0. But still, product is removed from the wishlist because of the qty not greater than 0.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I was able to identify parts of core code that control this behaviour but am unable to extend those classes to create own module.

First class is 'Mage_Wishlist_IndexController' which extends 'Mage_Wishlist_Controller_Abstract'. I modified function updateAction(). This is relevant part of the code. I only changed if sentence:

```
                if (isset($post['qty'][$itemId])) {
                    $qty = $this->_processLocalizedQty($post['qty'][$itemId]);
                }
                if (is_null($qty)) {
                    $qty = $item->getQty();
                    if (!$qty) {
                        $qty = 1;
                    }
                } elseif (0 > $qty) { // I changed this from (0 == $qty)
                    try {
                        $item->delete();
                    } catch (Exception $e) {
                        Mage::logException($e);
                        Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->addError(
                            $this->__('Can\'t delete item from wishlist')
                        );
                    }
                }
```

Now products don't get deleted anymore if $qty is set to 0

Second class is 'Mage_Wishlist_Model_Wishlist', function updateItem($itemId, $buyRequest, $params = null). I changed value at line 381, from

```
$qty = $candidate->getQty() ? $candidate->getQty() : 1;
```

to:

```
$qty = 0;
```

And function updateItem($itemId, $buyRequest, $params = null), I changed line

```
$resultItem->setQty($buyRequest->getQty() * 1)
```

to:

```
$resultItem->setQty($buyRequest->getQty())
```

Now default value for added items is 0.

How can I create correct observer to modify those two classes? What should be the event that triggers the observer?